# Hibernate OneToOne mapping with join table broken column mapping exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using Spring Boot/Spring Data JPA (Hibernate).  I have two entities, `WorkOrder` and `Inspection`.  A `WorkOrder` can have multiple `Inspection`s, but an `Inspection` can only be tied to one `WorkOrder`.  When a `WorkOrder` has one or more `Inspection`s, there needs to be some extra information, so I created a `WorkOrderInspection` entity as well.  Below are the classes.  With this configuration, I am getting a Hibernate mapping exception:

> broken column mapping for: workOrderInspection.id of: com.couplingcorp.qualitycontrol.domain.inspections.Inspection

What do I need to change to fix the error?  Or is there a better way of mapping this altogether?

**WorkOrder**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="manufacturing.workorders")
public class WorkOrder implements Serializable, Comparable<WorkOrder> {
    private int workOrderID;
    private List<WorkOrderInspection> inspections = new ArrayList<>();
    ...

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_workorderid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getWorkOrderID() {
        return workOrderID;
    }

    public void setWorkOrderID(int workOrderID) {
        this.workOrderID = workOrderID;
    }
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="workOrder",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    public List<WorkOrderInspection> getInspections() {
        return inspections;
    }

    public void setInspections(List<WorkOrderInspection> inspections) {
        this.inspections = inspections;
    }
}
```

**Inspection**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="qualitycontrol.inspections")
public class Inspection implements Serializable {
    ...
    private int inspectionID;
    private WorkOrderInspection workOrderInspection;
    ...

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_inspectionid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getInspectionID() {
        return inspectionID;
    }

    public void setInspectionID(int inspectionID) {
        this.inspectionID = inspectionID;
    }
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="inspection")
    public WorkOrderInspection getWorkOrderInspection() {
        return workOrderInspection;
    }

    public void setWorkOrderInspection(WorkOrderInspection workOrderInspection) {
        this.workOrderInspection = workOrderInspection;
    }
}
```

**WorkOrderInspection**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="manufacturing.workorders_inspections")
@IdClass(WorkOrderInspectionID.class)
public class WorkOrderInspection implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private WorkOrder workOrder;
    private Inspection inspection;
    private int dwgXPosition;
    private int dwgYPosition;

    public WorkOrderInspection() {
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_workorderid", referencedColumnName="pk_workorderid")
    public WorkOrder getWorkOrder() {
        return workOrder;
    }

    public void setWorkOrder(WorkOrder workOrder) {
        this.workOrder = workOrder;
    }

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_inspectionid", referencedColumnName="pk_inspectionid")
    public Inspection getInspection() {
        return inspection;
    }

    public void setInspection(Inspection inspection) {
        this.inspection = inspection;
    }

    @Column(name="dwgxposition", columnDefinition="decimal(4,0)")
    public int getDwgXPosition() {
        return dwgXPosition;
    }

    public void setDwgXPosition(int dwgXPosition) {
        this.dwgXPosition = dwgXPosition;
    }

    @Column(name="dwgyposition", columnDefinition="decimal(4,0)")
    public int getDwgYPosition() {
        return dwgYPosition;
    }

    public void setDwgYPosition(int dwgYPosition) {
        this.dwgYPosition = dwgYPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.workOrder);
        hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.inspection);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final WorkOrderInspection other = (WorkOrderInspection) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.workOrder, other.workOrder)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.inspection, other.inspection)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**WorkOrderInspectionID**

```
public class WorkOrderInspectionID implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private WorkOrder workOrder;
    private Inspection inspection;

    public WorkOrderInspectionID() {}

    public WorkOrderInspectionID(WorkOrder workOrder, Inspection inspection) {
        this.workOrder = workOrder;
        this.inspection = inspection;
    }

    public WorkOrder getWorkOrder() {
        return workOrder;
    }

    public void setWorkOrder(WorkOrder workOrder) {
        this.workOrder = workOrder;
    }

    public Inspection getInspection() {
        return inspection;
    }

    public void setInspection(Inspection inspection) {
        this.inspection = inspection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.workOrder);
        hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.inspection);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final WorkOrderInspectionID other = (WorkOrderInspectionID) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.workOrder, other.workOrder)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.inspection, other.inspection)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should completely remove WorkOrderInspectionID and just use WorkOrderInspection as a normal association table. Feels a lot cleaner and it will most likely help with your broken mapping as well

Comment: I ended up re-arranging some of my database tables so that my join table did not have extra columns.  This meant that I didn't even need the `WorkOrderInspection` class, and it was a much easier relationship.